# Laravel orWhere with related table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to get rows from a related table with:

```
        $Product->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $filters['search'] . '%')
                ->orWhere('brand', 'LIKE', '%' . $filters['search'] . '%');
```

But it is not working because it is only selecting from the `products` table.

My product model is:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'products';

    public function brands() {
        return $this->hasOne('ProductBrands', 'id', 'brand_id');
    }

    public function ages() {
        return $this->hasOne('ProductAges', 'id', 'age_id');
    }

    public function types() {
        return $this->hasOne('ProductTypes', 'id', 'type_id');
    }

    public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany('ProductImages');
    }

    public function toArray() {

        $ar = $this->attributes;

        $ar['brand'] = $this->brand;
        $ar['age'] = $this->age;
        $ar['type'] = $this->type;

        return $ar;
    }

    public function getBrandAttribute() {
        $brands = $this->brands()->first();
        return (isset($brands->brand) ? $brands->brand : '');
    }

    public function getAgeAttribute() {
        $ages = $this->ages()->first();
        return (isset($ages->age) ? $ages->age : '');
    }

    public function getTypeAttribute() {
        $types = $this->types()->first();
        return (isset($types->type) ? $types->type : '');
    }

}
```

With the relationship specified correctly I am unsure how to proceed.

How do I select from the main table and/or the related table `products_brands`?

---

After adding in the orWheres the rest of my filter has broken:

```
public function fetchProducts($filters, $sorts = null, $perpage = 2) {
    $Product = Product::query();
    if (!empty($filters['search']))
        $Product->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $filters['search'] . '%')
                ->orWhereHas('brands', function($q) use ($filters) {
                    $q->where('brand', 'LIKE', '%' . $filters['search'] . '%');
                })
                ->orWhereHas('types', function($q) use ($filters) {
                    $q->where('type', 'LIKE', '%' . $filters['search'] . '%');
                });
    if (isset($filters['type']))
        $Product->where('type_id', $filters['type']);
    if (isset($filters['brand']))
        $Product->where('brand_id', $filters['brand']);
    if (isset($filters['age']))
        $Product->where('age_id', $filters['age']);

    if (isset($sorts['sort']))
        $Product->orderBy($sorts['sort'], $sorts['sortdir']);

    return $Product;
}
```

If both `search` and one or more of the others is present e.g. `age`, it only obeys whats in if `(!empty($filters['search']))`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To write a where condition for a relationship you can use `whereHas`. (or `orWhereHas` in your caseI) [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations)

Try this:

```
$Product->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $filters['search'] . '%')
        ->orWhereHas('brands', function($q) use ($filters){
            $q->where('brand', 'LIKE', '%' . $filters['search'] . '%');
        });
```

#### Update

To be on the save side with all those wheres you better use a nested where

```
$Product = Product::query();
if (!empty($filters['search'])){
    $Product->where(function($q) use ($filters){
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $filters['search'] . '%')
        $q->orWhereHas('brands', function($q) use ($filters) {
            $q->where('brand', 'LIKE', '%' . $filters['search'] . '%');
        });
        $q->orWhereHas('types', function($q) use ($filters) {
            $q->where('type', 'LIKE', '%' . $filters['search'] . '%');
        });
}
if (isset($filters['type']))
    $Product->where('type_id', $filters['type']);
if (isset($filters['brand']))
    $Product->where('brand_id', $filters['brand']);
if (isset($filters['age']))
    $Product->where('age_id', $filters['age']);

if (isset($sorts['sort']))
    $Product->orderBy($sorts['sort'], $sorts['sortdir']);

return $Product;
```

Comment: I've only just noticed that this has broken something, please see my edit :)

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem, but use have to use an if with `{}` if the content is not just one line.

Comment: Is it applying the other ifs as ORs? because that would be wrong, those other ifs need to be ANDs and those orWhereHas' need to be in brackets in the raw SQL statement

Comment: You're welcome. Sadly I don't get any rep for comment upvotes... But hey, it's not like I would do it (only) for reputation ;)